# EntityFramework.Extended library do not work with connection string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Let me say,my database is mysql,Reference `EntityFramework.Extended` library in order to support batch update in `Entity Framework` .But EntityFramework.Extended library do not work with connection string in my `DbContext`

```
public MyContext() :base("DefaultConnection") this work!
```

//this does not work!

```
public MyContext() : base("server=localhost;user id=root;password=123456;database=AA;")
```

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=123456;persist security info=True;database=AA;charset=utf8;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider></providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**MyContext.cs**

```
 [DbConfigurationType(typeof(DbContextConfiguration))]
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
        //public MyContext() :base("DefaultConnection") this work!
        public MyContext() : base("server=localhost;user id=root;password=123456;database=AA;") //this do not work!
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("");
        }
    }
    public class DbContextConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public DbContextConfiguration()
        {
            EntityFramework.Locator.Current.Register<EntityFramework.Batch.IBatchRunner>(() => new MySqlBatchRunner());
        }
    }
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (var db = new MyContext())
            {
                var list = db.Users.ToList();

            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, in what way does it not work?

Comment: public MyContext() : base("server=localhost;user id=root;password=123456;database=AA;")  does not work ,raise an error ,root login error.But change to public MyContext() :base("DefaultConnection") work!

Comment: What is the exact error? Also, that connection string is not the same as the one from your web.config file.

Comment: But using public MyContext() : base("server=localhost;user id=root;password=123456;database=AA;")  and change [DbConfigurationType(typeof(DbContextConfiguration))] to [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))] work like a charm!

Comment: See this doc for details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html. The `[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]` highly recommended to be added for including all dependency resolvers for `MySql.*` classes.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I have no ideas

Comment: When using connection string name provided in web.config, all `MySql` dependencies are resolved by default using MySQL provider name. However when assigning `DBContext` to deal with MySQL connection string instead, the DB provider name of `DbContext` still not determined yet, hence it requires extra provider name configuration with `[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]` attribute.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I know,But I want to change connection dynamically... ,so must be connection string and support batch update,do not use provider name